# call the services within a mesh in ISTIO is working only with port number associate to the service name

Tags: istio

I am using Istio as a service mesh in AKS and set sidecar injection for all the services within the mesh.
I have been asked to use only services names (without their port numbers) for in cluster communication between the services. **I have two gRPC services: gRPC client service and gRPC Service (which has been defined to listen on port 5003). When i am using the following address from the client it is working great: "http://{service name}:5003" but when i am using the following address: "http://{namesapce}.{service name}" i keep getting error 500 and can get pass it**. According to what i have read, it's suppose to work wstrong textithout the port number but it doesn't. Can any one help me solve this ?

The following are the gRPC Service yaml and it's gateway, virtual service and destination rule i have set:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Yd7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjG1Y.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CkwD.png)

Comment: I think the address should be `service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local`, Could you try with that? 1.They're both in the same namespace?  2.Could you try to add mesh gateway like [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/)?

Comment: Hi, 
1) Both services belongs to "clipper" namespace (the same).
2) I did add a gateway (it is attached to my post) 

Thanks

Comment: Also, i have tried your suggestion to use "vice-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local" and i still getting error 500

Comment: Hi @N.Rotner have you managed to make it work? As far as I check grpc error 500 is Internal server error. Typically a server bug. So i'm not sure if that's related to istio. By `gateways.mesh` I mean that you can add it in your gateway  for communication inside the mesh. Take a look at below code  `hosts:
  - reviews.prod.svc.cluster.local
  - uk.bookinfo.com
  gateways:
  - some-config-namespace/my-gateway
  - mesh # applies to all the sidecars in the mesh`.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. I did not unserstand what shell i write in the "- mesh" part ?

Comment: It's part of virtual service configuration, there is an example in above link.